# Como comparo el texto ingresado para que no sea menor a .30 ni mayor a 2.00

Tags: java, validación, float, jtextfield

Intento Ingresar solo valores que esten en el rango de .30 hasta 2.00, intento usar un Integer pero al convertir esto a un Int es claro que no puede ser comparado con un float. no se si exista otro metodo para lograr esto.

```
txtHeight.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
             if(!(ke.getKeyChar() >= '0' && ke.getKeyChar() <= '9')&&!(ke.getKeyChar() == '.')&&!(ke.getKeyChar()== ',')){
                ke.consume();
            }
            if(ke.getKeyChar()=='.'&&txtHeight.getText().contains(".")){
                System.out.println("El caracter punto ya lo ingreso");
                ke.consume();
            }
            if((Integer.parseInt(txtHeight.getText()) <= .30)||(Integer.parseInt(txtHeight.getText()) >= 2.00)){
                ke.consume();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Datos correctos");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            
        }
    });
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Que tal si conviertes el texto  a float?

```
Float.parseFloat(txtHeight.getText())
```